# Issue with Dart DevTools in Android Studio: Can't Navigate to Code

Tags: flutter, macos, dart, android-studio, visual-studio-code

I'm encountering a perplexing issue with Dart DevTools in Android Studio that I hope someone can help me troubleshoot. Strangely, it was functioning perfectly fine on a different PC just last week. Here's a detailed description:

Problem Description:

When I launch Dart DevTools in Android Studio, it opens successfully without any error messages. However, when I click on screen elements within the DevTools interface, Android Studio does not navigate to the associated code file, which it should do. Interestingly, this navigation works flawlessly when I use Visual Studio Code (VSCode).

iam using mac air m1  and flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.2, on macOS 13.5.1 22G90 darwin-arm64,Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0,(Xcode 14.3.1),Android Studio (version 2022.3),Dart SDK version: 3.1.0 (stable) (Tue Aug 15 21:33:36 2023 +0000) on "macos_arm64"

Comment: Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.2, on macOS 13.5.1 22G90 darwin-arm64, locale
    en-EG)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.3.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.81.1)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] Network resources

Comment: Actual Behavior:

Instead, Android Studio does not navigate to the code file.

Additional Information:

I have tried restarting Android Studio.
I have also tried reinstalling Dart DevTools.
I can confirm that Dart DevTools navigation works correctly in VSCode on the same project.
I would appreciate any suggestions or insights into what might be causing this issue. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Shouldn't you maybe post the issue to Arduino Studio issues tracker?